# How to redirect if already logged in ngAA directive Angular

Tags: angularjs, laravel

My configuration is

```
  $authProvider.signinUrl = 'laravel-frontend/public/api/frontauthenticate';
    $authProvider.signinState = 'login';
    $authProvider.signinRoute = '/login';
    $authProvider.signinTemplateUrl = 'app/shared/views/login.html';
    $authProvider.afterSigninRedirectTo = 'dashboard';
    $authProvider.afterSignoutRedirectTo = 'login';
```

so after login it goes to dashboard but then when I write '/login' then it opens login page.

How can I redirect it to dashboard if it is already looged in .

Thanks.